# MediaElement.js: Source URL with Variables?

Tags: security, video-streaming, html5-video, cdn, mediaelement.js

After falling in love with MediaElement.js, I ran into a problem. On the site in question we use Bitgravity as our CDN. Bitgravity uses an MD5 hash to secure video URLs, added to the end as a variable. For example:

```
    http://stuff.blah.cdn.bitg.net/Secure/stuff/myvideo.mp4?h=3440203940902383938298394833324323
```

The result was MEj's "Download File" link, pointing to the page the code is on. After fooling around a bit, I found that the presence of a variable on the URL is triggering the problem.

Does anyone know of a way to make MediaElements.js accept a source URL with a variable such as this?

Comment: Here's a bit of a hack that made this work for me: Since I was using the Wordpress plugin of MediaElement, I looked at mediaelement-js-wp.php and found this:

` if ($src) {
  $attributes[] = 'src="'.htmlspecialchars($src).'"';
  $flash_src = htmlspecialchars($src);
 } `

It was commented out and replaced with longer code that helped MEj find files if you failed to give an extension. I wasn't worried about that, so I took the later out, uncommented this, and now my secure URLs work.